# Parse the Custom Log in HIVE

Tags: logging, hadoop, hive

I am new to HIVE. 
I have a log file that is separated by "\t", 
Example:
***A\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF ...***

I want to create a external table on this, I can use [FIELD SEPERATED BY "\t"] but

- I don't want all the columns, I only need few, for example 1,3
- One column has negative value, I want it to convert to positive.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have the following data in your log file (separated by '\t'):

```
a   123 b   c   d
x   -12 y   z
o   1   q
```

For the first requirement, the default Hive loader will read the columns that you specify. For example,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
c1 STRING, c2 INT, c3 STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '/user/joe/test';
```

We use the above statement to create a table `test`. If some row is `a\t123\tb\tc\td`, Hive will only use the first 3 columns. So you can use this feature to cut the useless columns in the end of rows. If you only need to use "c2" and "c3", you can select these two columns from `test` table and ignore "c1".

For the second requirement, you can use `ABS`. For example,

```
select c1, ABS(c2), c3 from test;
```

The above statement will output the following data:

```
a   123 b
x   12  y
o   1   q
```